# Can you save an edited RAW .dng file on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios10, cifilter, dng

I want to build an iOS 10 app that lets you shoot a RAW (`.dng`) image, edit it, and then saved the edited `.dng` file to the camera roll. By combining code from Apple's 2016 "**AVCamManual**" and "**RawExpose**" sample apps, I've gotten to the point where I have a `CIFilter` containing the RAW image along with the edits.

However, I can't figure out how to save the resulting `CIImage` to the camera roll as a `.dng` file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A RAW file is "raw" output direct from a camera sensor, so the only way to get it is directly from a camera. Once you've processed a RAW file, what you have is by definition no longer "raw", so you can't go back to RAW.

To extend the metaphor [presented at WWDC where they introduced RAW photography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-501/?time=1749)... a RAW file is like the ingredients for a cake. When you use Core Image to create a viewable image from the RAW file, you're baking the cake. (And as noted, there are many different ways to bake a cake from the same ingredients, corresponding to the possible options for processing RAW.) But you can't un-bake a cake — there's no going back to original ingredients, much less a way that somehow preserves the result of your processing.

Thus, the only way to store an image processed from a RAW original is to save the processed image in a bitmap image format. (Use JPEG if you don't mind lossy compression, PNG or TIFF if you need lossless, etc.)

If you're writing the results of an edit to [`PHPhotoLibrary`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-501/?time=1749), use JPEG (high quality / less compressed if you prefer), and Photos will store your edit as a derived result, allowing the user to revert to the RAW original. You can also describe the set of filters you applied in `PHAdjustmentData` saved with your edit — with adjustment data, another instance of your app (or Photos app extension) can reconstruct the edit using the original RAW data plus the filter settings you save, then allow a user to alter the filter parameters to create a different processed image.

---

<sup>Note: There is a version of the DNG format called [Linear DNG](http://www.barrypearson.co.uk/articles/dng/linear.htm) that supports non-RAW (or "not quite RAW") images, but it's rather rare in practice, and Apple's imaging stack doesn't support it.</sup>

Comment: Kinda what I figured. Apps like Lightroom must just bypass Core Image and do the RAW file manipulation directly to the file using their own methods.

That's a good tip about writing the image as JPEG to PHPhotoLibrary, thanks!

Comment: Lightroom etc can't un-bake the cake either. When they take a RAW file and save DNG, what they're doing is saving the original RAW data (which may be in a camera-specific file format like Canon or Nikon RAW), plus metadata describing your RAW processing settings, along with (typically) a JPEG preview of the processing results, into a common file format that can hold all of those things. The original RAW data remains unchanged, it's just repackaged into a different file that also contains other data.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately DNG isn't supported as an output format in Apple's ImageIO framework. See the output of CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers() for a list of supported output types:

```
(
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.png",
    "com.compuserve.gif",
    "public.tiff",
    "public.jpeg-2000",
    "com.microsoft.ico",
    "com.microsoft.bmp",
    "com.apple.icns",
    "com.adobe.photoshop-image",
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "com.truevision.tga-image",
    "com.sgi.sgi-image",
    "com.ilm.openexr-image",
    "public.pbm",
    "public.pvr",
    "org.khronos.astc",
    "org.khronos.ktx",
    "com.microsoft.dds",
    "com.apple.rjpeg"
)
```

Comment: Saw this right after I filed a radar about the RAW output support in ImageI/O framework. Absence of the support makes it impossible to even edit the EXIF and Geotag data of RAW, which I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes late, but it may help others with the problem. This is how I saved a raw photo to the camera roll as a .dng file.

Just to note, I captured the photo using the camera with AVFoundation.

```
 import Photos
 import AVFoundation 

 //reading in the photo data in as a data object
 let photoData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.dngPhotoDataRepresentation(forRawSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)

 // put it into a temporary file
 let temporaryDNGFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp.dng")!     
 try! photoData?.write(to: temporaryDNGFileURL)

 // get access to photo library
 PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            if status == .authorized {

                // Perform changes to the library
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

                    let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                    options.shouldMoveFile = true

                    //Write Raw:
                    PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset().addResource(with: .photo, fileURL: temporaryDNGFileURL, options: options)

                    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
                        if let error = error { print(error) }
                })

            }
            else { print("cant access photo album") }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't edit the photo before saving, as the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get DNG data as of the writing of this response (iOS 10.1) is:

```
AVCapturePhotoOutput.dngPhotoDataRepresentation(forRawSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?)
```

Noting the OP refers to Core Image. As mentioned by rickster, CI works on processed image data, therefore only offers processed image results (JPEG, TIFF):

```
CIContext.writeJPEGRepresentation(of:to:colorSpace:options:)
CIContext.writeTIFFRepresentation(of:to:format:colorSpace:options:)
```